EXPO / EXPO GO IOS APP: Filed to parse manifest. The operation couldn't be copiled (EXUpdates.UpdateError error 1)
I have a problem with expo go application on IOS device (Android is working). When i try to connect to my project using expo start or expo start --tunnel it throw following error: error in expo go ios app
What I miss? When i open app using android device eveything is working fine. I try to solve it but no progress. Here are my package.json and app.json with eas.json:
package.json:

{
  "name": "prometeuszai",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.21.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "@rneui/base": "^0.0.0-edge.2",
    "@rneui/themed": "^0.0.0-edge.2",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "expo": "~49.0.15",
    "expo-av": "~13.4.1",
    "expo-file-system": "~15.4.3",
    "expo-privacy-manifest-polyfill-plugin": "^0.0.2",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "firebase": "^9.7.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.8.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.6",
    "react-native-media-query": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.1",
    "react-native-purchases": "^7.27.1",
    "react-native-really-awesome-button": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^14.1.0",
    "react-native-three-dots-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "private": true
}

app.json:
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Prometeusz Ai",
    "slug": "prometeuszai",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/bot.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/bot.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "plugins": ["expo-privacy-manifest-polyfill-plugin"],
    "runtimeVersion": "@string/expo_runtime_version",
    "extra": { "eas": { "projectId": "c5fc9c8a-f854-4529-9c0b-6964b1da2ade" } },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.kliemk.prometeuszai",
      "privacyManifests": {
        "NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes": [
          {
            "NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType": "NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp",
            "NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons": ["CA92.1"]
          },
          {
            "NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType": "NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryDiskSpace",
            "NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons": ["CA92.1"]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/bot.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.kliemk.prometeuszai"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/images/bot.png"
    }
  }
}

eas.json:
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.16.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleDebug"
      },
      "ios": {
        "buildConfiguration": "Debug"
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}

Thank you for help!
I expected to open application on IOS Expo Go app like on Android.

hi there! what version of the Expo Go app do you have installed?

Hello! Thx for response, I have client version 1027611 in app info and it said that supported SDKS 51

I'm update version of expo to 51 and another depencencies, but still the same error /:

Im dealing with this error today too. My iphone updated expo go to version 23.1 and now I cant load my app...

@brentvatne Do you know the answer to this?

No, i don't find answer for it /:

facing the same issue, this is where the error comes from: https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/1d0c82906811bdbfb0d5762f8a46d3cf582aa339/packages/expo-updates/ios/EXUpdates/AppLoader/FileDownloader.swift#L824

@actuallyakash have you find any workaround?

@JakubKlimas nothing at the moment.

Were all screwed. We HAVE to update our project to expo 51… there is a big reddit on this. Bunch of ppl stuck updating dependencies all day
https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/s/VVEuuPyl7o

Can you link the reddit?

@BlakeMcFarlane. https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/s/VVEuuPyl7o
